# Reusable groups of properties or traits in Alice fixtures generator

Tags: symfony, fixtures, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

It's possible to describe fixture inheritance in Alice:

```
// template.yml
Nelmio\Entity\User:
    user (template):
        username: '<username()>'
        age: '<numberBetween(1, 20)>'
```

--

```
include:
  - template.yml

Nelmio\Entity\User:
    user1 (extends user):
        name: '<firstName()>'
        lastname: '<lastName()>'
        city: '<city()>'
        age: '<numberBetween(1, 50)>'
```

What about defining reusable collections of properties (similar to Traits)?

What if I want to be able to define a template with two properties, e.g.

```
createdAt: <(new \DateTime('2016-01-01'))>
updatedAt: <(new \DateTime('2016-01-02'))>
```

and then use those in any template without having to redefine these properties for each entity?

I know Alice supports multi-inheritance. e.g.:

```
Nelmio\Entity\User:
    user_bare (template):
        username: '<username()>'
    user_full (template, extends user_bare):
        name: '<firstName()>'
        lastname: '<lastName()>'
        city: '<city()>'
```

This, however, does not seem to be the way forward due to the fact that each template has to be defined under the same namespace (`Nelmio\Entity\User`), while Traits should be good to use in any namespace.

Is there a clean way to reuse groups of fixture properties in any namespace?

Comment: Looks like a feature request, don't hesitate to submit your request on the github project https://github.com/nelmio/alice/issues